# contractDictionary.Type does not have a member named aDictionary

Tags: ios, swift

The following code produces the error

> contractDictionary.Type does not have a member named aDictionary

but I don't understand why or how to fix it.

```
import Foundation

class contactDictionary {

var aDictionary:[Contact] = [Contact]()
var bDictionary:[Contact] = [Contact]()
var cDictionary:[Contact] = [Contact]()
var dDictionary:[Contact] = [Contact]()
var eDictionary:[Contact] = [Contact]()
var fDictionary:[Contact] = [Contact]()
var gDictionary:[Contact] = [Contact]()
var hDictionary:[Contact] = [Contact]()
var iDictionary:[Contact] = [Contact]()
var jDictionary:[Contact] = [Contact]()
var kDictionary:[Contact] = [Contact]()
var lDictionary:[Contact] = [Contact]()
var mDictionary:[Contact] = [Contact]()
var nDictionary:[Contact] = [Contact]()
var oDictionary:[Contact] = [Contact]()
var pDictionary:[Contact] = [Contact]()
var qDictionary:[Contact] = [Contact]()
var rDictionary:[Contact] = [Contact]()
var sDictionary:[Contact] = [Contact]()
var tDictionary:[Contact] = [Contact]()
var uDictionary:[Contact] = [Contact]()
var vDictionary:[Contact] = [Contact]()
var wDictionary:[Contact] = [Contact]()
var xDictionary:[Contact] = [Contact]()
var yDictionary:[Contact] = [Contact]()
var zDictionary:[Contact] = [Contact]()
var numDictionary:[Contact] = [Contact]()


var contactDictionary:(String, [Contact]) = ["a": aDictionary,
"b": bDictionary,
"c": cDictionary,
"d": dDictionary,
"e": eDictionary,
"f": fDictionary,
"g": gDictionary,
"h": hDictionary,
"i": iDictionary,
"j": jDictionary,
"k": kDictionary,
"l": lDictionary,
"m": mDictionary,
"n": nDictionary,
"o": oDictionary,
"p": pDictionary,
"q": qDictionary,
"r": rDictionary,
"s": sDictionary,
"t": tDictionary,
"u": uDictionary,
"v": vDictionary,
"w": wDictionary,
"x": xDictionary,
"y": yDictionary,
"z": zDictionary,
"#": numDictionary]
}
```

Do I need to declare the variables elsewhere or in a different way?

Comment: Are you trying to assign a dictionary to a tuple?

Comment: var contactDictionary:[String: [Contact] ] =